# Why is zoom level interpreted different in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Comparing maps from openlayers, leaflet and mapbox-gl-js, I can see that mapbox-gl-js has a different map image for the same center and zoom combination, and the same div size. It seems to zoom in one level extra compared to the openlayers and leaflet maps. Why is this?

Answer (score 6):

yep that's correct. this one level difference is because the vector tiles used by mapbox-gl-js are 512px and in openlayers/leaflet/mapbox.js the raster tiles used are 256px. in other words, the appearance of a 512 tile at zoom level 0 is the same as the appearance of a 256 tile at zoom level 1. hope this helps!

[image: 512px tile 0/0/0]

512px tile 0/0/0

[image]

256px tile 1/0/0

Comment: Thank you, one follow-up question, if software is implementing the mapbox style specification, should it do the same as mapbox gl js is doing? I guess it should since the default tileSize in the style spec is 512? I don't see anything explicit about this though in the style spec. TIA.

Comment: you can still use 256px tiles in mapbox-gl-js (for example mapbox satellite tiles are still 256px), so I recommend you use whatever tilesize your source data is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the zoomFactor of OpenLayerMap like this to make same as mapbox-gl

```
const view = new View({
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom,
        zoomFactor: 2.38
})
```

Also you should set the tileSize to 512 in openlayer map setting